# I am trying to do chisquare testing across all columns in R

Tags: r, chi-squared

My Data:

```
dependent <- c(1,0,1)
Salutation <- c("MR","MR","MR")
Gender <- c("MALE","MALE","MALE")
Profession <- c("BUSINESS","OTHER","BUSINESS")
Region <- c("South","West","Midwest")
CUST_RES_CITY <- c("MUMBAI","BANGALORE","BANGALORE")
Vertical_New <- c("AGENCY 1","AGENCY 1","AGENCY 2")
VehicleMake  <-c ("SUZUKI","HONDA","VOLKS") 
model<- c("SWIFT","MOBILIO","POLO")
Segment <- c("5 to 10 Lacs","10 to 30 Lacs","5 to 10 Lacs")


factor.cs <- data.frame(dependent, Salutation ,Gender ,Profession ,Region, CUST_RES_CITY,Vertical_New,VehicleMake ,model,Segment)
```

Previously I had this piece which would do chi square testing and would return statistic from it.

```
corr.factor <- factor.cs %>%
summarise_each(funs(chisq.test(., 
                               factor.cs[,dependent])$statistic), -one_of(dependent))
```

Now since the summarise_each is changed to summarise_at,_all etc.I tried to modify the code

```
corr.factor <- factor.cs %>%  
 summarise_all(funs(chisq.test(., factor.cs$dependent)$statistic))
 %>% select(-c("dependent"))
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: 'x' and 'y' must have at least 2 levels
```

Comment: The reason for your error in this example is that both Gender and Salution are factors with 1 level. Change one Salutation into MRS and one Gender into FEMALE